# How to a make a cloud from an outline and blend it into a photo of a skyline

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I'm trying to take an outline and blend it in as a cloud in a photo I took. I've tried rendering clouds within the black outline and then mushing it around with the Liquify filter (not pictured), but it still doesn't really blend in well.

How do I get it to look more like a natural cloud pattern?

[image: Photoshop Screenshot]

EDIT: Thanks for the help. I used the answer/comment below, plus a strong blur. Here is the result!

[image: Final version from answer]

Comment: That is way too small to have so much detail in a cloud in relation to the rest of the image. Its never going to look right as it stands. See how even clouds that kind look like something are huge in the background (ie: that one piece sticking up and then jeering to the right)? That's how clouds look, not like tiny detailed things completely isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu could try:

Select the black of the FSM , then hide the fsm layer.

Keep the selection active, make a new layer and add a layer mask. The mask should now look like the selection (check the thumbnail of the layer mask). Deselect.

Click on the thumbnail of the blank layer so that the thumbnail is highlighted rather than the layer mask.

Use the clone tool with a large-ish radius and clone portions of the clouds, painting them onto the blank layer which you attached the layer mask to.

You should only see the cloned portions appear where the black lines of the FSM would be. If not, then click on the layer mask to give it focus and then the mac equivalent of shift+ctrl+i. (this should invert the mask).

Comment: I added a strong Gaussian Blur after using this technique. It came out really well. Thanks!